# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC Error While creating Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I've created Windows service which needs to create Excel after every 2 hrs. 
But its is giving me an error as follows

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

First Time it creates excel file.but 2nd time it gives error.
tried many things but failed. please help me out.

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005.
```

this error also comes after first error came.

```
public void WriteExcel()
    {
        string ExcelGen = "ExcelGen";
        try
        {
            string fileNm = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_HH") + ".xls";
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Uploads\\" + fileNm;
            string ServiceDbName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceDBName"].ToString();
            string ServiceLMName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceTable"].ToString();
            int Cnt = Service1.Counter;

            Service1.AddLog("EXCEL STEP 1");
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objexcelapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();                
            objexcelapp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            objexcelapp.Columns.ColumnWidth = 25;
            Service1.AddLog("EXCEL STEP 1.1");
            MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Conn"].ToString());
            MySqlCommand inCmd = new MySqlCommand("select HT_LeadCode as 'LeadCode',right(lead_phone1,10) as 'Mobile',idg_fnc_GetDispositionDescription(lead_service_id, lead_last_dial_status) as 'Status' from " + ServiceDbName + "." + ServiceLMName + " where lead_status ='F' and HT_LeadCode <> '' and ifnull(HT_UpldFlag,'N') = 'N'", Conn);
            Conn.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(inCmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
            Service1.AddLog( "EXCEL STEP 2");
            string leadCodes = "";
            foreach (System.Data.DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < table.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    Service1.AddLog(" i : " + i.ToString());
                    objexcelapp.Cells[1, i] = table.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                }

                for (int j = 1; j < table.Rows.Count+1; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 1; k < table.Columns.Count+1; k++)
                    {
                        Service1.AddLog("j & k : " + j.ToString()+ " & " + k.ToString());
                        objexcelapp.Cells[j + 2, k + 1] = table.Rows[j].ItemArray[k].ToString();
                        if(k==0)
                            leadCodes += table.Rows[j].ItemArray[k].ToString() + ",";
                    }
                }
            }
            Service1.AddLog("LeadCodes : "+leadCodes);
            leadCodes = leadCodes.Substring(0, leadCodes.Length - 1);
            Service1.AddLog("LeadCodes : " + leadCodes);

            inCmd = new MySqlCommand("update " + ServiceDbName + "." + ServiceLMName + " set HT_UpldFlag = 'Y' where lead_status ='F' and HT_LeadCode <> '' and ifnull(HT_UpldFlag,'N') = 'N' ", Conn);
            inCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Service1.AddLog( "EXCEL STEP 3");
            Service1.AddLog( "'" + path + "'" + " File is Created");
            objexcelapp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(path);
            objexcelapp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
            objexcelapp.Quit();
            Conn.Close();
            Service1.AddLog( "EXCEL STEP 4");
            Service1.AddLog( "UPLOAD THREAD STARTING");
            Activity act = new Activity();

            act.Upload();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Service1.AddLog( "WriteExcel Err : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

When I Run service, very first time it creates excel file but when the interval takes place. it gives above mentioned error.

Answer (score 1):

Gulp.

I've seen that 0x800A03EC error plenty of times, and it can mean anything...

You might want to try this...

- Grab a copy of this [free C# library](http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm) which creates .xlsx file using
  the OpenXML library, rather than VSTO.   It uses the `OpenXmlWriter` library to write to the file, so if there's a lot of data, you *won't* get out-of-memory issues.
- Create your Excel file by populating your ds DataSet as before, then using one line of code:

  CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(ds, "YourExcelFilename.xlsx");

If you don't want to go down this route, I'd recommend you dispose of your `objexcelapp` variable.  This is a COM object which might remain open/in-use if you don't specifically kill it.

```
if (objexcelapp != null)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objexcelapp);
```

We've had loads of VSTO problems over the years, and now, use it as little as possible.

Hope this helps.